# Error transforming EPSG:4326 to EPSG:90013

Tags: coordinate-system, epsg, geomajas

When I'm trying to run a map on geomajas an error has occurred:

> o.g.internal.service.GeoServiceImpl - Problem during transformation
>   EPSG:4326->EPSG:900913 of MULTIPOLYGON

The multipolygon coordinates are x = -170 and y = -85.0511... .

Comment: we're going to need more information than that :-) at least the whole error message, plus the multipolygon coordinates

Comment: Thanks for your reply, error is   o.g.internal.service.GeoServiceImpl - Problem during transformation EPSG:4326->EPSG:900913of MULTIPOLYGON and multipolygon coordinates are x = -170 and y = -85.05112877980659

Comment: As an aside, you should really be using EPSG:3857 instead of EPSG:900913 - they both represent the same projection, but the latter is deprecated, and may not be supported in future GIS applications.

Comment: as per your suggessetion, i have replaced EPSG:3857 instead of EPSG:90013, transformation error has been solved but another error has been occured,  ERROR o.g.i.r.p.t.StringContentTilePainter - Unable to write this tile's feature fragment org.geomajas.rendering.RenderException: Unexpected end of attribute.

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is with the bounds of EPSG:3857, the "WGS84 Pseudo-Mercator" projection. It has latitude limits of +/- 85 degrees. So your point of -85.05... is outside the bounds, and is undefined/untransformable. You'll need to use a projection that covers greater latitudes, and the choice of that will be very much based on the extents of your data, the levels of accuracy which you're willing to accept, whether there is going to be other layers from other projections, and so on.

Comment: when seeting EPSG:3857, error of transformation has been occured, error is-  o.g.internal.service.GeoServiceImpl - Problem during transformation EPSG:4326->EPSG:3857of MULTIPOLYGON

Comment: I know - 3857 == 900913. As I said in my reply, your problem is that your polygon is outside the bounds of the projection.

Comment: in mapmain.xml has set EPSG:3857 and it's coordinates are x = 8185000 and y = 1975000 is there problem in this xml? please give me a hint how can i solve this problem..

Comment: which projection have to used for cover greater lattitudes..

Answer (score 0):

In Geomajas, you can define the transformable area for pairs of projections. See http://files.geomajas.org/maven/trunk/geomajas/docbook-devuserguide/html/master.html#ch-crs
When a transformable area is defined, geometries are clipped to fall inside this area. This should solve the transformation problem for you.

In any case, you should post the full stack trace of the exception (maybe on something like pastebin and linking that here). This can give useful hints for solving the problem.